# Jacoco Maven plugin - include test sources

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jacoco-maven-plugin

I'm new in Jacoco maven plugin and trying to add coverage analysis for my test classes (I'm using TestNG with failsafe plugin).

After checking the documentation and some tutorials I made it work on classes in **Sources Root** (src/main), but couldn't manage to include the classes in **Tests Root** (src/test). My project consists of only test classes, so the coverage report is required only for these.

In IntelliJ, there is an option "Enable coverage in test folders" which does what I really want. So I think there should be a way to enable these folders in plugin configurations as well.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. Coverage measures the proportion of production code exercised by test code. What's the point in measuring the proportion of test code exercised by itself?

Comment: You could try out this patch to the `jacoco-maven-plugin`:  https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/271

Comment: @HaraldWellmann, the module I'm working with consist of UI automation tests and utility classes. All of them are in src/test folders. If you check IntelliJ's option to include the test sources, you'll see it provides a good coverage report for these too.

Comment: @heenenee, thanks for the tip. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved what I wanted by adding 0.7.6-SNAPSHOT version of jacoco, thanks to [heenenee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2646526/heenenee).

Cloned and built the [mentioned version of jacoco](https://github.com/cristcost/jacoco), installed the jar locally (different instructions [here](http://softwarecave.org/2014/06/14/adding-external-jars-into-maven-project/)) and added the tests in coverage data by configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <includeTests>true</includeTests>
</configuration>
```